# What is the right way of providing custom metadata to file uploaded to GCP Storage bucket? Using node.js sdk

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been struggling to provide custom metadata to uploaded file. Here is the code:

```
const uploadResponse = await GCS.bucket(bucketName).upload(filePath, {
    destination: filedir + filename,
    metadata: {
      custom1: 'customValue1',
      custom2: 'customValue2'
    },
  });
```

The file upload is working alright but the custom metadata attributes seem to be ignored. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well for those who may stumble upon this, here is how it works:

```
const uploadResponse = await GCS.bucket(bucketName).upload(filePath, {
    destination: filedir + filename,
    metadata: {
      metadata: {
        custom1: 'customValue1',
        custom2: 'customValue2'
      }
    },
  });
```